# Solution for a Fredholm integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

I have an integral equation: $\int_0^T( t^\alpha + s^\alpha -|t-s|^\alpha) \phi(s)ds=\lambda\phi(t)$ for $\alpha\in(0,2)$. I think this is a Fredholm equation but I am not sure how to solve it. Appreciate any assistance.

Thanks,
Ido.

Comment: Do you have a background about the subject of integral equations?

Comment: A little. I will appreciate any references that can assist here.

Comment: Can it be assumed that $0\le t\le T$?

Comment: Yes, this is the case.